# Angular 4 - remove the current row from a table

Tags: angular, rxjs, state-management

I would like to remove the current row from a table by clicking a delete link.

I use the codes below to display the data

**services**

```
getMembers(): Observable<any> {
  return this._http.get('http://localhost/membership/main/getUsers')
  .map(response => response.json() );
}
```

**components**

```
members$: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.members$ = this._membersService.getMembers()
}

delete(id) {
 this._membersService.deleteUser(id);
}
```

**html**

```
<a (click)="delete(member?.id, i)">
```

I heard about splice function. but I cant find a way how to use it in observable.

Comment: You need to subscribe and you are getting all members, you just need one to remove one user so hopefully your deleteUser(id) method is correctly removing that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have much bigger problems here, I think.

There's indeed no *simple* way to remove a single line `T` from an array which is held by an `Observable<T[]>`. I recommend you to go a regular route:

```
members: any[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._membersService
    .getMembers()
    .subscribe(members => this.members = members);
}

delete(memberIndex: number): void {
  this.members.splice(memberIndex, 1);
}

<a (click)="delete(i)">
```

---

The reason you want to hold the result data in a field is your template.
I bet in your template code you have something similar to `*ngFor="let member of members$ | async"`. The problem is that this code will result in reevaluation of `members` on every change detection cycle. That means, the remote API will be called numerous time, when it's absolutely not necessary!

---

Having said that, I must mention that my answer would be completely different if you said that you use (say) [`@ngrx/store`](https://github.com/ngrx/store) for data management. But since this is not mentioned in your question, I assume, it is out of the picture.

Otherwise, you could also use `BehaviorSubject`, but I don't recommend to do that with your current setup. It would be better to put the `BehaviorSubject` in your service and expose it as an `Observable`.

Comment: ahhh.. so you mean I need to avoid the use of observable? when should I use observable?

Comment: Well, you should not avoid Observables. They are actually a _good_ thing. The issue is, they are _read-only_, and it conflicts with your scenario where you want to modify the observable. It's just darn hard. So, you have three choices basically: a) the simplest one is not to use them in this particular case; just subscribe and store the result in a field; 2) harder, but better in a complex app -- use ngrx/store; 3) last one is to use `Subject<T[]>` which acts like observable, but also allows getting its current value (this option is actually dirty IMO).

Comment: Sorry. For option three I should have said `BehaviorSubject` which has [`getValue()` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue)

Comment: alright thanks yes you did. I will not use observable in this case